# PHP connection Wamp+Solr

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to setup and test a connection using php.
Below you will notice I have not defined base, which will be my home directory for the 'require_once'. My question is regarding what needs to be on the line for require once?

```
<?php
define('base', 
require_once( 'C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sqltest' );
$options = array
(
    'hostname'  => 'localhost',
    'login'     => 'root',
    'password'  =>'',
    'port'      => '8983',
    'path'      => 'C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sqltest'
);

    $client = new SolrClient( $options );

    if ( ! $solr->ping() ) {
        echo 'Solr service not up dude.';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

My local server was setup using Wamp. Many pages I have looked at for help use another service and their request_once is like this:

```
require_once( 'Apache/Solr/Service.php' );
```

this leads me to believe mine should point to something in my wamp directory

Comment: do not use absolute paths (like in include/require). This is NOT solving your include dir/autoloader problem, just masks it. Not to mention portability etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I am missing the solr php client
https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client